# How to use RedisTemplate to store different datatypes

Tags: redis

I am using Spring RedisTemplate to deal with operations related to Redis. Will I be able to store two datatypes. For example I want to store Key,String as well as Key,Integer. How to acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/redis.html ?

Altering a bit from docs, untested:

```
public class Example {

  // inject the actual template 
  @Autowired
  private RedisTemplate<String, String> template;

  // inject the template as ValueOperations
  @Resource(name="redisTemplate")
  private ValueOperations<String, Integer> intOp;

  @Resource(name="redisTemplate")
  private ValueOperations<String, String> stringOp;

  public void sampleKeySetting() {
    intOp.set('my_int_value', 10);
    stringOp.set('my_string_value', 'good!');
  }
}
```

There are `XXXXOperations` for other data structures too: check http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-keyvalue/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/keyvalue/redis/core/RedisOperations.html